# Repeated Consecutive Digital Product Sum Convergence

Tags: code-golf, sequence

Given a positive integer `n` (***Example: `n=1234444999`***)

- Separate into consecutive digit runs:

  - `[1, 2, 3, 4444, 999]`
- Take the digital product of each run.

  - `[1, 2, 3, 4*4*4*4, 9*9*9] = [1, 2, 3, 256, 729]`
- Sum it...

  - 991
- Repeat until this converges to a single number:

  - 1234444999
  - 991
  - 82
  - 10
  - 1
- Return last number.

---

## Test Cases

```
BASE CASES:
0 = 0
...
9 = 9

OTHER CASES:
1234444999                     = 1
222222222222222                = 8
111222333444555666777888999000 = 9
11122233344455566677788899     = 8
1112223334445                  = 6
14536                          = 1
99                             = 9
```

## Requested Example:

```
334455553666333
9+16+625+3+216+27
896
8+9+6
23
2+3
**5**
```

## Winning?

It's [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest byte-count is the winner.

Comment: Annnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnd... this is NOT the sandbox. Crap. Well, not much I can do now, sorry all ._.

Comment: It would be good to have test cases where digits of the same kind aren't all in a consecutive chunk.

Comment: Can we take input as a list of digits? Some languages can't support integers as high as `11122233344455566677788899`.

Comment: @ETHproductions you may state the maximum integer input allowed by your language and have your answer be valid if you can explain the bounding.

Comment: Will the same digit evet appear in 2 different runs, eg: `33445555666333`?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I mean... You're repeating the process until it converges to a single digit. The intermediate steps have many different examples of that.

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>7</s> <s>6</s> 5 bytes

Thanks to *Emigna* for saving a byte!

```
vSγPO
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/LPjc5gD///8NDQ2NjIyMjY1NTExMTU3NzMzMzc0tLCwsLS0NDAwA)

Comment: I just now noticed for the first time that your avatar is a doge meme.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn and you just made me notice that as well...

Comment: You could replace `gF` with `v`.

Comment: @Emigna Oohh of course! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>17</s> <s>15</s> 13 bytes

```
e".+"_¬ò¦ x_×
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=ZSIuKyJfrPKmIHhf1w==&input=IjExMTIyMjMzMzQ0NDU1NTY2Njc3Nzg4ODk5Ig==) Takes input as a string.

Still not satisfied with this answer...

#### Explanation

```
e".+"_  ¬ ò¦  x_  ×
e".+"Z{Zq ò!= xZ{Zr*1}}

e".+"                     Repeatedly replace all matches of /.+/ (the entire string)
     Z{               }   Z with this function:
       Zq                   Split Z into chars.
          ò!=               Partition at inequality; that is, split into runs of equal items.
              xZ{    }      Take the sum of: for each item in Z:
                 Zr*1         the item reduced by multiplication (i.e. the product).
                          This procedure is repeated until the same result is yielded twice.
                          Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Comment: You can also just take it as an integer and state the maximum allowable input, sorry, I changed my answer after posting it to my default answer for that question.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Oh, hey, thanks. That saves two bytes, anyway...

Comment: Also, the `x_×` combined with `I'm unsatisfied` made me laugh. Thanks ;).

Comment: I thought `ß` might have been the way to go here. I was wrong! (At least at half 5 in the morn', sat on the bus to  the airport I was!)

Comment: "Still not unsatisfied" ... so ... you're satisfied finally?

Comment: @Zacharý Haha, I caught that right before you commented. Nope, still unsatisfied :P I'm thinking I should change something in Japt to make the `".+"` unnecessary...

Answer (score 6):

## Jelly, 9 bytes

```
DŒgP€SµÐL
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/l6KT0gEdNa4IPbT08wef///9GqAAA)

Here's how it works:

```
D  - input as a list of digits
Œg - group runs of equal elements
P€ - the product of each element
S  - the sum of the list
µ  - syntax stuff to separate the left from the right
ÐL - repeat until we get a result twice, then return that result.
```

Comment: Why doesn't P automatically vectorize? That seems strange...

Comment: No, P automatically vectorizes, so you don't need the `€`.

Comment: No, P doesn't vectorize: https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/l6KT0gOBDWw9P8Pn//78RKgAA

Comment: Oh, I see - `Œg` is inconsistent when there's only a single group. What's the reasoning behind that?

Comment: No clue at all!

Comment: It looks like it's because Jelly automatically unpacks singleton lists. I don't see why that's very useful, though...

Comment: Make sure you look carefully though, as how Jelly displays strings and lists is ... weird.

Comment: Very late I know, but `P` and `S` *do* vectorise, but along columns, not rows

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, <s>55</s> 42 bytes

```
#//.i_:>Tr[Times@@@Split@IntegerDigits@i]&
```

*-13 bytes from  @JungHwan Min*. Thanx!

in case someone wants to use this as a random-digit-generator,
here is the tally of the first 100.000 numbers

> {{1, 17320}, {2, 4873}, {3, 10862}, {4, 11358}, {5, 10853}, {6, 
>     9688}, {7, 11464}, {8, 10878}, {9, 12704}}
>   *or if you gamble, don't put your money on 2!*

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
Ḋ|ẹḅ×ᵐ+↰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUEAvv9icmFjaHlsb2cy///huIp84bq54biFw5fhtZAr4oaw//8xMTEyMjIzMzM0NDQ1NTU2NjY3Nzc4ODg5OTkwMDD/Wg)

#### Explanation

```
Ḋ          Input = Output = a digit
 |         Or
  ẹ        Split into a list of digits
   ḅ       Group consecutive equal elements together
    ×ᵐ     Map multiply
      +    Sum
       ↰   Recursive call
```

Comment: You'd never expect Brachylog to outgolf Jelly here would you?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer When Brachylog beats Jelly, my first assumption is that the Jelly answer isn't optimal

Comment: Mine too, except I tried to do this in Jelly too. The thing is, well, 05AB1E still beats this. :)

Comment: Well. it's one byte, and the Jelly answer is by me, yeah, I'd expect Brachylog to beat Jelly.

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
us^M_MrjGT8
```

[Try it online.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=us%5EM_MrjGT8&input=1234444999&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A1234444999%0A222222222222222%0A111222333444555666777888999000%0A11122233344455566677788899%0A1112223334445&debug=0) [Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=us%5EM_MrjGT8&input=1234444999&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A1234444999%0A222222222222222%0A111222333444555666777888999000%0A11122233344455566677788899%0A1112223334445&debug=0)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 96 bytes

```python
from itertools import*
f=lambda n:n*(n<10)or f(sum(int(k)**len([*g])for k,g in groupby(str(n))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jYuxDoMgFEV3v4LxQTqACGrTfknTQVOxpvIgiINfT3FoYocmvds991y/xadDmZIJzpIpDiE6Ny9kst6FyApznTvbPzqCZ2SAF8GpC8TAslqYMMKLMjYPCDc23qnJ0@s0kgnJGNzq@w2WGABpTvJh9w2IUlY5bdtSWnxg@Z3DIoTIQMr9pJTSWtd13TRN/nPO/xJ/SUdeKakPfT@lNw)

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>77</s> <s>73</s> <s>67</s> 65 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @CraigAyre*

```js
f=s=>s>9?f(''+eval(s.replace(/(.)\1*/g,s=>'+'+[...s].join`*`))):s
```

#### How?

The input ***s*** is transformed into an arithmetic expression with:

```js
s.replace(/(.)\1*/g, s => '+' + [...s].join`*`)
```

For instance, `1234444999` becomes `+1+2+3+4*4*4*4+9*9*9`.

We evaluate this expression and do a recursive call with the result until it's boiled down to a single decimal digit.

#### Test cases

```js
f=s=>s>9?f(''+eval(s.replace(/(.)\1*/g,s=>'+'+[...s].join`*`))):s

console.log(f("1234444999"                    )) // = 1
console.log(f("222222222222222"               )) // = 8
console.log(f("111222333444555666777888999000")) // = 9
console.log(f("11122233344455566677788899"    )) // = 8
console.log(f("1112223334445"                 )) // = 6
console.log(f("14536"                         )) // = 1
console.log(f("99"                            )) // = 9
```

Comment: Can you save a couple of bytes by comparing against 9?: `f=s=>s>9?f(''+eval(s.replace(/(.)\1*/g,s=>'+'+[...s].join\`*\`))):s`

Comment: @CraigAyre Seems like my approach was a bit overcomplicated indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
ωöṁΠgmis
```

Takes and returns an integer.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fe2J98aOmxqJD2/6f7zy87eHOxnML0nMzi////2/AZchlxGXMZcJlymXGZc5lwWXJZWhkbAIElpaWXEaogMvQ0BBIGRuDFJiampqZmZmbm1tYWADVGhgY4JFGleIyNDE1NuOytAQA)

### Explanation

Having a built-in for base 10 digits would be nice...

```
ωöṁΠgmis
ω         Iterate until a fixed point is found
 ö        the composition of the following four functions:
       s   convert to string,
     mi    convert each digit to integer,
    g      group equal adjacent integers,
  ṁΠ       take product of each group and sum the results.
```

Comment: ...looks like incorporating a built-in for base 10 digits during the intervening 3 years was worth it, then: [now 6 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8f/5To2HOxvPLUhP@f//f7ShkbEJEFhaWuoYoQIdQ0NDIGVsDFJgampqZmZmbm5uYWEBVGtgYIBHGlVKx9DE1NhMBygM4gNVAnlmZkDJWAA).

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 113 bytes

```php
for(;9<$a=&$argn;$a=$s){$s=0;preg_match_all('#(.)\1*#',$argn,$t);foreach($t[0]as$v)$s+=$v[0]**strlen($v);}echo$a;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYyxCsIwGIT3Pkb7Y5NapFWXkAYH6eCii5tKCCU2Qm3Dn9BF9NVj6E133x1njQ3NwRqbaMQJJWo7oX@NPfm18ny5no4t5Qko7EeR1tvdPooxlvLwnJBw1oASq6Xm0YGjH3Ci4hZ1L9/Kd0aqYSB5Rjb0XhdZXi7bEjzl8UCrzhDwt@qhHMwU3FrAHFNROI@DHkmE/Ks7M4HiIfwB)

Comment: Are you  full-time PHP developer?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn No I have experience over  few years

Answer (score 2):

## MATL, 11 bytes

```
`!UY'^sVtnq
```

Try it at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=%60%21UY%27%5EsVtnq&inputs=%27111222333444555666777888999000%27&version=20.2.0)

**Explanation**

```
        % Implicitly grab input as a string
`       % Do...while loop
  !U    % Convert the string to an array of numbers (the digits)
  Y'    % Perform run-length encoding
  ^     % Raise the digits to the power corresponding to the number of times they
        % occurred consecutively
  s     % Sum the result
  V     % Convert to a string
  tn    % Duplicate and determine the number of characters in the string
  q     % Subtract one, causes the loop to continue until it's a single digit
        % Implicit end of do...while loop and display
```

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 22 bytes

```
r_,{1/e`Wf%::i::#:+s}*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vyhep9pQPzUhPE3VyirTykrZSru4Vuv/f0NDQyMjI2NjYxMTE1NTUzMzM3NzcwsLC0tLSwMDAwA)

Answer (score 2):

## Braingolf, 25 bytes

```
!L1-Mv[RG(d&*)&+!L1-Mv>]R
```

Will add a TIO link once I get Dennis to pull the latest version, as using greedy operators inside `(...)` loops is currently broken on TIO

### Explanation

```
!L1-Mv[RG(d&*)&+!L1-Mv>]R  Implicit input from commandline args
!L1-M                      Push length of input minus 1 to stack2
     v                     Switch to stack2
      [.........!L1-Mv>]   While length of input > 1..
       RG                  Split into digit runs
         (d&*)             Product of digits of each item in stack
              &+           Sum stack
                        R  Return to stack1
                           Implicit output from stack
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <strike>103</strike> <strike>70</strike> 69 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
until(<10)$sum.map product.group.map(read.pure).show
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYq7CsIwGEZ3n@IfHBIoIWlsm4LdHPUJRCTY1oY2F3LBx4/p6OJZPvjOWWRYp23LWWlnfYSLjJJcVYiHeUgmqg2dGcXHkDTR0oHzdkyvSN7eJrc/yE9yJC75CZOw2E/WUhkYoKjbE5DzykQgMGO4s5qfCn3fV1D/UgFjrCzne9I0Tdu2XdcJIUpNKf3nH/kL)

Comment: You can shorten that a lot by using `until(<10)`. Also the `map(read.pure)` can be moved before `show`, which saves parentheses.

Comment: Yup, it is a lot better!

Comment: You can use `$` instead of the outer parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), <s>17</s> 23 bytes

+6 bytes from handling cases where the same digit is present in multiple chunks

```
{+/*/'(&~=':x)_x:10\x}/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqlpbX0tfXUOtzlbdqkIzvsLK0CCmolb/f5q6oqEBV5q6oZGxCRBYWloqGKECBUNDQyBlbAxSYKpgaGJqbKYAVAbimwKBsZmZGVDyPwA)

- `{...}/` run a converge reduction over the input
- `x:10\x` convert input to a list of digits, updating `x`
- `(&~=':x)` identify indices where the value differs from the previous element
- `(...)_x` split the list of digits on those indices
- `*/'` take the product of each chunk
- `+/` add those products together

Fails on inputs too large for 64-bit integers.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>114</s> 104 bytes

```r
n=scan(,'');while(nchar(n)>1){n=el(strsplit(n,''));b=table(n);n=as.character(sum(strtoi(names(b))^b))};n
```

reads from stdin; returns the answer as a string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCoAgEAXQ4zQDEbQWO0owipBgv3AmWkRnt1y83autwWsU0DgM7O4tl0SIm1QCLzM/8KmQWtWzZCP0xS54k9AjO3jRqX@JlirptfdtRybInpQC8/p7HVr7AA)

Comment: You could use `paste` instead of `as.character`. The former coerces its input into `character` type ;-)

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>97</s> 96 bytes

```
a=scan(,"");while(nchar(a)>1){a=paste(sum(strtoi((b<-rle(el(strsplit(a,""))))$v)^strtoi(b$l)))}a
```

Slightly different approach than the [other answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132030/56131) using **R**.

This answer makes use of the `rle` function, which `compute[s] the lengths and values of runs of equal values in a vector`.

*-1* bytes thanks to @Giuseppe !

Comment: `**` is equivalent to `^`

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 50 bytes

49 bytes of code + `-p` flag.

```perl
s/(.)\1*/"+".$&=~s%.%$&*%gr.1/ge while($_=eval)>9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcpBCsIwEEDR/ZwixqS0FSdO0oiDxJMUiovQCkFCC7rz6jEu/Zu3@TmuyZf9LlfFMZfNtNiN1Bt5kKia8Nk0atX0el6RzBzFe3mk2KopxNc9dTcuV6EmgUHI8SnLCQgsXICBrBtqzAz2PyCiinO/wQMN3p2B@Qs)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 19 bytes

```
=ò¦ m¬®×Ãx)<A?U:ßUs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUIAvf9qYXB0//89w7LCpiBtwqzCrsOXw4N4KTxBP1U6w59Vc///IjExMTIyMjMzMzQ0NDU1NTY2Njc3Nzg4ODk5OTAwMCI)

### Explanation:

```
=ò¦ m¬®×Ãx)<A?U:ßUs
=                    // Implicit U (input) =
 ò¦                  //   Split the input into an array of consecutive digit runs
    m¬               //   Split each inner array: ["1","22","333"] -> [["1"],["2","2"],["3","3","3"]]
      ®              //   Map; At each item:
       ×             //     Get the product of each run
        Ã            //   }
         x           //   Sum
           <A        // <10
             ?       // If true:
              U      //   return U
               :     // Else:
                ß    //   Run the program again; Pass:
                 Us  //     U, cast to a string
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 45 bytes

```ruby
:!~&(:digits|:slice_when+:!=|:*&(:/&:*)|:sum)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWN3WtFOvUNKxSMtMzS4prrIpzMpNT48szUvO0rRRta6y0gHL6alZamkCp0lxNiKb1BQpu0YZGxiZAYGlpGQsRXbAAQgMA)

### Explanation

```
:!~ & (:digits | :slice_when + :!= | :* & (:/ & :*) | :sum)

:!~ & (                                                   )  # Apply the following function until F(x) == x
       :digits |                                             #   Get digits
                 :slice_when + :!= |                         #   Group like elements (slice between unequal)
                                     :* & (:/ & :*) |        #   Map with reduce with product
                                                      :sum   #   Sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3) `g`, 6 bytes

```
ᵡλġᵛΠ∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJnIiwiIiwi4bWhzrvEoeG1m86g4oiRIiwiIiwiOTkiLCIzLjQuMiJd)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

I/O as digit arrays

```
£=òÎx_×Ãì
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=oz3yznhf18Ps&input=WzEsMSwxLDIsMiwyLDMsMywzLDQsNCw0LDUsNSw1LDYsNiw2LDcsNyw3LDgsOCw4LDksOSw5LDAsMCwwXQ)

```
£=òÎx_×Ãì     :Implicit input of digit array
£             :Map
 =            :  Reassign to U
  ò           :  Partition between elements where
   Î          :    The sign of their difference in truthy (not zero)
    x         :  Reduce by addition
     _        :  After passing each through this function
      ×       :    Reduce by multiplication
       Ã      :  End function
        ì     :  Split to digit array
              :  Implicit output of last element
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), <s>69</s> 68 bytes

```
f={r->r>9?f((r=~/(.)\1*/)*.tap{}.sum{n->n[1]as int**n[0].size()}):r}
```

Requires Groovy 3.x.

### Explanation

If the input is single digit, returns it, else recursively calls the function on the next pass of the algorithm.

```
f={r->r>9?f(...):r}     : Recursively call algorithm if input > 9, else return input
r=~/(.)\1*/)            : Regex capture of each run, e.g. [["444", "4"], ["2", "2"]]
*.tap{}                 : Convert Matcher to List<List<Integer>> so we can call sum()
.sum{...}               : Apply the closure to each List element and sum them
n[1]as int**n[0].size() : <digit>^<run length> from e.g. ["444", "4"]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](https://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Jan-14)</sup>, <s>20</s> 17 bytes

```
⍥(/+⊜/×+1.-@0°⋕)∞
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_9_0__ZiDihpAg4o2lKC8r4oqcL8OXKzEuLUAwwrDii5Up4oieCgpmIDAKZiA5CmYgMTIzNDQ0NDk5OQpmIDIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMgpmIDk5Cg==)